# Interesting Subgroups of $SU(2^n)$

Tags: lie-groups

I'm a physicist, so please forgive me if this question is wrong or simplistic, but are there any subgroups of $SU(2^n)$ which are isomorphic to $SU(k)$ for some $k \geq 2$, which do not have a non-trivial intersection with $SU(2)^{\otimes n}$ (i.e., not just $\mathrm{id}^{\otimes n}$)?

Comment: "Not contain any element": could you be more precise: you mean that you require that the intersection of this copy $SU(k)$ with any conjugate of $SU(2)^{\otimes n}$ is reduced to $\{\mathrm{id}\}$? to scalar matrices? Also, when you say "isomorphic to $SU(k)$, you really want isomorphic and don't allow a quotient of $SU(k)$ by a finite central subgroup? — e.g., for $k=2$, you're not interested in subgroups isomorphic to $SU(2)/\pm 1\simeq SO(3)$?

Comment: PS the notation $SU(2)^{\otimes n}$ is meant to denote the image of $SU(2)^n$ by the $n$-th tensor power of its standard 2-dimensional representation.

Comment: @YCor: I don't know exactly what a scalar matrix is, but I'd like the intersection between these two groups to be trivial. I'm willing to allow the identity operator to be in the intersection, and any multiple $e^{i\theta} \mathrm{id}$.

Comment: A scalar matrix is a multiple $\lambda I_n$ of the identity matrix (with the determinant 1 condition, $\lambda$ has to be a $n$-root of 1). So yes, this amounts to asking the intersection to consist of scalar matrices.

Comment: So, I think that a random conjugate of the standard copy of $SU(2)$ works (for any $n\ge 4$).

Comment: @YCor: Is there a book I can try to read which will explain in further detail?

Comment: No, it's just an expectation... Basically with heuristic arguments, the product $SU(2)^{\otimes n}$ has dimension $3n$ ($12$ when $n=4$). This is inside $SU(2^n)$, of dimension $4^n-1$ ($255$ when $n=4$). The subgroup $SU(2)$ has dimension $3$; the set of its conjugates is parameterized by the $2$-Grassmanian, which has dimension $2.(2^n-2)$ ($28$ when $n=4$); it sounds reasonable to expect that some conjugate will avoid this 12-dimensional subgroup. This is not rigorous, anyway, and not even "evidence".

Comment: $SU(2)$ has irreducible representations of every positive integer dimension. So why don't you just take the irreducible representation of dimension $2^n$ as your embedding? The only issue is that minus the identity is in the intersection, so to cure this, take a sum of representations of dimension $2^{n-1}-1$ and $2^{n-1}+1$, so that it's really a representation of $SO(3)$, which is centreless.